# Show default wallpaper in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

Is it possible to display default wallpaper that user has on their android phone to ImageView?
If yes what code should I use to achieve this please.

Comment: Yea , its possible !

Comment: @Kdblue, What code can I use to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
val wallpaperDrawable = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).drawable
imageView.setImageDrawable(wallpaperDrawable)
```